React app makes infinite requests to backend server
I making a chat app in react. I'm finding trouble in the ChatWindow component that displays all the chats. These chats are called from a backend server. This component is somehow making infinite amount of requests to the backend server which is crashing it. It also buffers the chats multiple times simultaneuosly. I used the network tab in dev tools and it showed 117 reqs in less than 10 secs. I faced the same problem in Sidebar.jsx. See the image: Output of network tab in devtools
Here is Sidebar.jsx:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Menu, Drawer, Button } from 'react-daisyui';
const api = `http://localhost:8000`;

function Sidebar({ onRecipientChange }) {
    const [menuItems, setMenuItems] = useState([])
    const [nick, setNick] = useState('')

    const handleFriendSelect = (nickname, email) => {
        onRecipientChange(nickname, email)
    }

    const fetchFriends = (async () => {
        if (!window.localStorage.getItem('e')) {
            const response = await axios.get(`${api}/users/profile/friends?email=${window.localStorage.getItem('mail')}`);
            const res = response.data.values;
            const frnds = JSON.parse(res);
            let items = [];

            if (Array.isArray(frnds) && frnds.length > 0 && res !== '["Start"]') {
                const requests = frnds.map(async (friend) => {
                    const r = await axios.get(`${api}/users/profile?email=${friend}`);
                    return r.data.values[0].nickname;
                });

                const nicknames = await Promise.all(requests);

                items = nicknames.map((nickname, index) => (
                    <Menu.Item onClick={() => handleFriendSelect(nickname, frnds[index])} style={{ borderRadius: 3 }}>
                        {(nickname) ? nickname : "None"}
                    </Menu.Item>
                ));
            } else {
                items.push(
                    <Menu.Item key="None" style={{ borderRadius: 3 }}>
                        None
                    </Menu.Item>
                );
            }

            setMenuItems(items);
        }
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFriends()
    }, [menuItems])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchNick() {
            if (!window.localStorage.getItem('e')) {
                const res = await axios.get(`${api}/users/profile?email=${window.localStorage.getItem('mail')}`)
                setNick(res.data.values[0].nickname)
            }
        }
        fetchNick()
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <Drawer open={true} side={
                    <>
                        <Menu className="bg-base-200 rounded-sm text-lg h-full" style={{ width: 250 }}>
                            <Menu.Title className='text-xl' style={{ color: 'gray' }}>
                                <span className='flex justify-between'>
                                    {nick}
                                    <Button
                                        color='ghost' size='sm' className='btn-circle'
                                        onClick={
                                            async function logout() {
                                                window.localStorage.removeItem('mail')
                                                window.location = '/login'
                                            }
                                        }
                                    >
                                    </Button>
                                </span>
                            </Menu.Title>
                            <Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Title className='text-lg'>Me</Menu.Title>
                                <Menu.Item style={{ borderRadius: 3 }}>
                                    Profile
                                </Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Item style={{ borderRadius: 3 }}>
                                    Inbox
                                </Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Item style={{ borderRadius: 3 }}>
                                    Friends
                                </Menu.Item>
                            </Menu.Item>
                            <Menu.Item>
                                <Menu.Title className='text-lg'>Chats</Menu.Title>
                                {menuItems}
                            </Menu.Item>
                        </Menu>
                    </>
                } />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Sidebar


Here is ChatWindow.jsx:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Navbar, Input, Join, ChatBubble } from 'react-daisyui';
import axios from 'axios'
const api = `http://localhost:8000`;

function ChatWindow({ recipientNickname, recipientEmail }) {
    const client = window.localStorage.getItem('mail')
    const [chats, setChats] = useState([])

    async function fetchChats() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${api}/users/messages?client=${client}&recipient=${recipientEmail}`);
            if (response.data) {
                setChats(response.data);
            } else {
                setChats([]);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchChats()
    }, [chats])

    const chatBubbles = chats.map((message, index) => (
        <ChatBubble key={index} end={message.client === client}>
            <ChatBubble.Message>{message.message}</ChatBubble.Message>
        </ChatBubble>
    ))

    return (
        <div style={{ margin: 250, marginTop: 0, zIndex: 1 }}>
            <div>
                <Navbar>
                    <Navbar.Center style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <Button tag="a" color="ghost" className="normal-case text-xl">
                            {recipientNickname || "Chats"}
                        </Button>
                    </Navbar.Center>
                </Navbar>
            </div>
            <div className='chats'>
                {chatBubbles}
            </div>
            <div>
                <div style={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 5, left: 0, right: 0 }}>
                    <Join>
                        <Input style={{ width: 1000, marginLeft: 260 }} placeholder='Send a message' className='join-item' />
                        <Button className='join-item rounded-s' color='success'>
                           Send
                        </Button>
                    </Join>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ChatWindow

Here is the backend route code:
const axios = require('axios')
module.exports = {
route: "users/messages",
method: 'GET',
run: async(req, res) => {
const { client, recipient } = req.query
axios.get(require('../api')('Messages'))
.then((response) => {
const [headerRow, ...rows] = response.data.values;
            const Data = rows.map(row => {
                const obj = {};
                headerRow.forEach((key, index) => {
                    obj[key] = row[index]
                })
                
                return obj
            })

            const result = Data.filter(entry =>
            (entry.client == client && entry.recipient == recipient)
                ||
            (entry.client == recipient && entry.recipient == client)
            )

            // console.log(result)
            res.send(result)
        })
}

}
UPDATE: I removed the dependency variables from useEffect, but now the chats don't load at all in ChatWindow...

Your fetchFriends function updates menuItems; you call fetchFriends via a useEffect that is triggered when menuItems changes. You need to change the logic to remove this infinite loop

Because you use menuItems as a dependence in the useEffect which inside you call the fetchFriends function which updates the menuItems with setMenuItems which creates an infinity loop, the same for fetchChats
You need to have an empty dependences array
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFriends()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchChats()
    }, [])


Thanks for pointing out the mistake, I made the changes accordingly but now when a menuItem is clicked, the chats in ChatWindow don't appear at all...its just a blank screen, the backend server is functioning properly as well.

There's an old adage that computers only do what you tell them to do - you've programmed an infinite loop. Setting state inside useEffect will cause it to update and then call useEffect again:
"Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update." - https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

One of the common mistakes to avoid in a useEffect is updating in the dependancy array within a it. It's important to understand how the useEffect hook works. By setting setMenuItems(...) within the use effect which runs every time you make a change to menuItems, you are effectively creating an infinite loop.
On your Sidebar you have
    const fetchFriends = (async () => {
        if (!window.localStorage.getItem('e')) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
        setMenuItems(...); //this code triggers your useEffect to run
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFriends()
    }, [menuItems])//any change in this variable will cause the use effect to run again

You also made the exact same mistake in your ChatWindow.

hey, i fixed that by removing the variable from the dependency array, but now the chats aren't loading at all.

Was leaving the dependency array empty the only thing you did or did you change other things? How exactly do you want your chat window to work? Have you tried a debugger or using print statements to verify that your route is correct or that your server sent the right information back to your client? The main idea of the dependency array is to tell your application when the use effect has to run, and that's it. I don't see any obviously wrong code with your chat window. Try to debug it with print statements.
